Symplectic reduction of a gauge theory in the presymplectic formalism
According to the O'Farrill's lecture note on this topic, (Hamiltonain) BRST quantization of a gauge theory corresponds to the quantization of the symplectic reduction of its classical theory.
(If I'm already wrong at this point, please let me know)
While there are many nice explanations for BRST formalism, as well as symplectic reduction of finite dimensional classical theories(such as a particle motion), I'd like to find a classical, field-theorietical example of the latter.
Is there any good reference to find explicit construct of

presymplectic reduction of
classical gauge field theory (Maxwell theory best, but nonabelian Yang-Mills theory or Chern-Simons theory are welcome as well)
where phase space is equipped with presymplectic form in the manner of presymplectic formalism?

I've searched and read several candidates, but the last condition did not meet yet. In the Maxwell theory, for example, I want the presymplectic form being treated is $\delta A_i \wedge \delta F^{i0}$.
If you have one, please share me the reference.

Link to O'Farrill's lecture?

@Qmechanic https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/BRST/Notes.pdf
